# how to set value of checkbox, if the checkbox is not checked the value will be send to database as "0" in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, checkbox

this is my view

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="box" id="busy" <?=($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] != 0)? "checked":""?> / >
                <label for="busy">Busy</label>
            </div>
            <br><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="dropdownHolder" name="restaurant_busy">
                            <option value="1" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '1')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>30 minute</option>
                            <option value="2" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '2')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>60 minute</option>
                            <option value="3" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '3')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>90 minute</option>
                            <option value="4" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '4')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>120 minute</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

this is my jquery :

```
$(function() {
   var selected = $('#dropdownHolder option:selected'), // Seems to be unused
       $busy = $('#busy'), // Always cache your queries
       $dropdown = $('#dropdownHolder'); // Caching queries

   $dropdown.hide(); // Hidden by default initially

   $busy.change(function () {
       if ($busy.prop('checked')) {
           $dropdown.show().focus().click();
       } else{
           $busy.prop('checked', false);
           $dropdown.blur().hide();
       }
   });

   $busy.change(); // This sets initial state
```

});

```
$("#edit_restaurant").submit(function() {
    $("#edit_restaurant").attr('action', '/VENDOR/Vendor/change_restaurant/');
    this.submit();
});
```

here is my controller for update

```
function change_restaurant(){

    if(!isset($_COOKIE["vendor_login"])){ redirect("/VENDOR",'refresh'); }
    if(!$this->Token_m->m_check_token($this->input->cookie('vendor_login'),$this->input->cookie('vendor_token'))){
        setcookie('vendor_login', '', time() - 3600, '/');
        redirect('/VENDOR/',"refresh");
    }
    if ($this->input->cookie('vendor_login') != null) {
        $admin_name = $this->input->cookie('vendor_login');

        setcookie('vendor_login', $admin_name, time() + 28800, '/');
        $msg = $this->input->cookie('vendor_token');
        setcookie('vendor_token', $msg, time() + 28800, '/');
    }

    if($vendorname = $_COOKIE["vendor_login"]) {

        $check_login = $this->Vendor_m->m_get_user_by_vendor($vendorname);
        $restaurant_id = $check_login["restaurant_id"];
        {

            if ($_POST == NULL){
                redirect("/VENDOR/Vendor/vendor_setting","refresh");
            }
            $data = array(
                "restaurant_busy" =>$this->input->post("restaurant_busy"),
                "restaurant_active" =>$this->input->post("restaurant_active"),
                "delivery_active" =>$this->input->post("delivery_active"),
                "takeaway_active" =>$this->input->post("takeaway_active"),
                "voucher_active" =>$this->input->post("voucher_active"),

            );
            $this->Vendor_m->m_update_restaurant_info($data,$restaurant_id);
        }
    }redirect("/VENDOR/Vendor/vendor_setting","refresh");
}
```

and this is my model

function m_update_restaurant_info($data, $restaurant_id)
    {

```
    $this->db->where("restaurant_id", $restaurant_id);
    $this->db->update("uhd_restaurant", $data);
}
```

value 1, 2, 3 and 4 is from the the dropdown menu, and with database table field name is "restaurant_busy", and i want if the checkbox is not checked, will be update as "0" value into restaurant_busy, i can u help me?

Comment: can u show me how to do it?, i think that is my answer what im trying to find @moped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll add a hidden input and update it's value based on option selected from dropdown ( select element ), also we will remove `name="restaurant_busy"` from select and move it to hidden input so that it's value is submitted, so your html will look like this...

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" id="busy" <?=($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] != 0)? "checked":""?> / >
    <label for="busy">Busy</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="hidden" id="restaurantBusyInput" name="restaurant_busy" value="<?=$restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"]?>">
        <select id="dropdownHolder">
            <option value="1" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '1')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>30 minute</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '2')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>60 minute</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '3')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>90 minute</option>
            <option value="4" <?php if ($restaurant_info["restaurant_busy"] == '4')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>120 minute</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be your JS

```
$(function() {
    var selected = $('#dropdownHolder option:selected'), // Seems to be unused
        $busy = $('#busy'), // Always cache your queries
        $dropdown = $('#dropdownHolder'), // Caching queries
        $hiddenInput = $( '#restaurantBusyInput' );

    $dropdown.hide(); // Hidden by default initially

    $busy.change(function () {
        if ($busy.prop('checked')) {
            $dropdown.show().focus().click();
        } else{
            $hiddenInput.val( '0' );
            $dropdown.blur().hide();
        }
    });
    $dropdown.change( function () {
        if ( $dropdown.val() ) {
            $hiddenInput.val( $dropdown.val() )
        } else {
            $hiddenInput.val( '0' )
        }
    } );

    $busy.change(); // This sets initial state
} );
```

Here we set our hidden input to 0 if select has no value or checkbox is unchecked. Lemme know how it goes ;)

Comment: its still doesn't work, when i tried uncheck the check box, than i submit i don't get the value, than the submit value still on the last submitted